# CSS gradient header animated fit full open screen

Tags: html, css

this is my first post, I would like to know if anyone can help me with that, I want to creat a gradient animated background in the header that fit the page.

```
header {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #f3a9cb, #c1a5ce, #97c5ea, #fdd1a3);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 8s infinite;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 10% 10% 18% 10%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 0 45px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some example or provided us more information about your question ?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to animate, e.g. moving just one linear gradient or changing from on linear gradient to another or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job for me, and remember you can adjust the keyframes animation however you like try to play with the values

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #f3a9cb, #c1a5ce, #97c5ea, #fdd1a3);
  background-size : 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 8s infinite;
  padding: 10% 10% 18% 10%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 0 45px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting someone to help me so quickly, thank you :)